# Best and highest use of last year's phonebook

Tags: home, office-supplies, books, lifespan, stationery

What is the best way to re*use* (as opposed to re*cycle*) a prior year's phone book?

---

*Meta: I checked the [on-topic](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [off-topic](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) lists and the question does seem to fit here, though the automatic filter seems to disagree.*

Comment: The problem to be solved is essentially a disposal or waste management one, of dealing with the old phonebook.  It asks for a better solution than simple recycling.

Answer (score 1):

Individual white pages work well for glass cleaning wipes (along with Windex or equivalent).